# How to use certain elements in a list to compare elements in other lists and output a certain element if duplicates are found in Python?

Tags: python, list, compare

I am new here (and new to programming).
I have tried to locate the relevant questions with no luck.

Basically, I got some lists shown below:

```
[0, 'a', 1, 3, 3.3, 220, 22.27]
[0, 'b', 1, 13, 3.3, 220, 23.19]
[0, 'c', 1, 23, 3.3, 220, 24.11]
[1, 'a', 1, 3, 3.5, 200, 20.02]
[1, 'b', 1, 43, 3.3, 220, 25.94]
[2, 'a', 1, 3, 3.3, 250, 26.86]
```

I would like to use list items of indices `1`, `2` and `3` as the comparison key and search within all the lists available with the given key.

If found, then I need it the output to be made up of the list items of indices `0`, `4`, `5` and `-1`.

So, with the given lists, the desired procedure is shown below.

First round:

- comparison key : `'a'`, `1`, `3`
- go through the available lists
- found the same key in

  > [0, **'a', 1, 3,** 3.3, 220, 22.27]
  >
  > [1, **'a', 1, 3,** 3.5, 200, 20.02]
  >
  > [2, **'a', 1, 3,** 3.3, 250, 26.86]
- then create the output

  > 0, 3.3, 220, 22.27
  >
  > 1, 3.5, 200, 20.02
  >
  > 2, 3.3, 250, 26.86

I have no idea how to code this yet, so could anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide any code you got so far. Are you looking for groups of three, only?

Comment: I would try to break this problem down a bit conceptually and then build each part up in sections.

1. You want to be able to search a list to see if it contain a subset
2. You want to be able remove a subset if it is contained in a list
3. You want to run this filter over multiple lists
4. You want to print the output of a set of lists.

Try solving the parts individually and then combine the individual parts to form the full solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@wagaman: Hi Pal, Here a little snippet to do this job:

```
universe = []
universe.append([0, 'a', 1, 3, 3.3, 220, 22.27])
universe.append([0, 'b', 1, 13, 3.3, 220, 23.19])
universe.append([0, 'c', 1, 23, 3.3, 220, 24.11])
universe.append([1, 'a', 1, 3, 3.5, 200, 20.02])
universe.append([1, 'b', 1, 43, 3.3, 220, 25.94])
universe.append([2, 'a', 1, 3, 3.3, 250, 26.86])


def extract_from_lists(universe, keys=[1,2,3], matches=['a',1,3]):
    if len(keys) == len(matches):
        for l in universe:
            valid = True
            for i in range(len(keys)):
                if l[keys[i]] != matches[i]:
                    valid = False
                    break
            if valid:
                print("{},{},{},{}".format(l[0],l[4],l[5],l[-1]))
    else:
        print('Keys List and Matches List length must be equal.')


extract_from_lists(universe)
```

If you need further information about it, let me know, it's a very simple comparison and use basic concepts of python as default values of arguments, iteration and so.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first define the input data:

```
some_lists = [[0, 'a', 1, 3, 3.3, 220, 22.27],
              [0, 'b', 1, 13, 3.3, 220, 23.19],
              [0, 'c', 1, 23, 3.3, 220, 24.11],
              [1, 'a', 1, 3, 3.5, 200, 20.02],
              [1, 'b', 1, 43, 3.3, 220, 25.94],
              [2, 'a', 1, 3, 3.3, 250, 26.86]]
```

We have to iterate over the sublists of `some_lists`. To that end we will use an index variable, say `x`. For each sublist `x` we need to check whether `x[1] == 'a' and x[2] == 1 and x[3] == 3` is fulfilled or not. This logical expression can be simplified through [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) to `x[1:4] == ['a', 1, 3]`. For those `x` that match the condition, we create the desired output by selecting the specified items, namely `[x[0], x[4], x[5], x[-1]]`. All this logic can be readily implemented through a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in just one line of code:

```
In [253]: [[x[0], x[4], x[5], x[-1]] for x in some_lists if x[1:4] == ['a', 1, 3]]              
Out[253]: [[0, 3.3, 220, 22.27], [1, 3.5, 200, 20.02], [2, 3.3, 250, 26.86]]
```